# CodingBat hasBad "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java

Hey guys I was hoping someone could explain to me the error in this code? I'm just having a little trouble understanding why it's throwing that exception.

[image: screenshot from codingbat]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first condition checks for the minimum length of string which should be 3. So "bad" and "xba" passes the first condition.

Lets go with `bad` first.

The second condition has two `OR` clauses and string "bad" satisfies the first of two `OR` clauses at line no 3. And hence the answer is `TRUE`

Now with `xba`..
The first of two `OR` clauses fails, so it checks for the second one. And here `str.substrin(1, 4)` throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the number of character in the String `xba` is only 3.

I would simple do a STRING.regionMatches() as below

```
String testString  = "bad";  
String givenString = "xxbad";  


boolean zeroIndexMatch = givenString.regionMatches(true, 0, testString, 0, 3);  
boolean firstIndexMatch = givenString.regionMatches(true, 1, testString, 0, 3);  

if (zeroIndexMatch || firstIndexMatch) {  
    System.out.println(true);  
} else {  
    System.out.println(false);
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I switched the opening conditional statement to if(str.length() > 3) and I figured out the work around is to add an additional if statement underneath.                                        if (str.length() == 3){
   return str.substring(0,3).equals("bad") ? true : false; 
  }

Comment: I would simple do a STRING.regionMatches() as below
<!-- language-all: lang-java -->
    `String testString  = "bad";
  String givenString = "xxbad";
  
  boolean zeroIndexMatch = givenString.regionMatches(true, 0, testString, 0, 3);
  boolean firstIndexMatch = givenString.regionMatches(true, 1, testString, 0, 3);
  
  if (zeroIndexMatch || firstIndexMatch) {
   System.out.println(true);
  } else {
   System.out.println(false);
  }`

Answer (score 2):

The tested String `"xba"` has the length *3* with the indices from *0* to *2*.
Your second method call of `substring` is `str.substring(1,4)`. Therefore it tries to read the indices *1* till *3* ([the endIndex **4** is *exclusive*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)). So you're trying to read from index *3*, but since the String isn't long enough to have such index, you're getting the mentioned Exception.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `str.substring(1, 4)` method it is causing a problem with that 7th test because it is only using a string that is 3 characters long.  By trying the access that fourth character you are going out of the string's bounds, and therefore getting the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.